# Setting number of slides to include in FlexSlider pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, flexslider

I have a [FlexSlider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) carousel setup similar to this example:

http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html

These are two linked carousels, the thumbnail carousel at the bottom can be used to navigate through the top slides.

I can use the `controlNav` option to output pagination links, like the dots under the carousel on the [FlexSlider homepage](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/).

**However, a pagination link will be output for each and every slide. Instead I'd like just the number of visible "rows" of thumbnails to be output.**

Taking the example linked to above, say there's three rows of thumbnails which can be navigated through, the pagination links might look like this:

[image]

Is this possible with FlexSlider? I don't want a dot for each slide, but of each visible "pane" of thumbnails.

Comment: I think you would need to pass in the manualControls property and use the slider.pagingCount property to create another navigation mode

Comment: do you pretty much want this functionality but using the dots instead of arrows? http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html

Comment: Essentially, yes. The arrows on the bottom slider that is.